# In Azure, how do I start a continuous WebJob that was uploaded programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

As part of an automation, I have created a WebJob that gets HTTP-uploaded to a WebSite application that places eveything into the expected folders [as described here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/#.U80vmbG2Uo6) (the indirection is mostly to save upload-bandwidth). The only problem now is, that this WebJob won't start running until I load the WebSite's Dashboard in the [management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

I have tried to mimic the web requests the portal does when showing the Dashboard within my application in the hopes of doing what's necessary, but so far I have been unable to find the correct call (-sequence?). I don't really expect GetAutoScaleCostInfo or GetMonitoringConfiguration to help…

What's the magic pixie dust I'm missing and the portal is doing?

Comment: You don't need to upgrade to the Standard/Basic instance if you don't want to, just signup for a paid or free account on Pingdom or similar services and have it check at a 5 minute interval and you're good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure the WebJob (and Website) is always running (and will always run) you need to set the **Always On** configuration setting, this will make sure the WebJob is started and keeps going (for a continuous WebJob).

Note that it is only available for standard/basic website instances.

In general to start the WebJob container you need to make an http request to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net (providing your deployment credentials as basic auth).

Comment: I have decided to go with the WebSiteExtensionsClient from the SDK, but of course, this does the request behind the scenes.

Comment: @Amit - So if the WebJob's run mode is set to "Continuous" in the portal but "AlwaysOn" is *not* set on the website, I assume the WebJob will stop running once the website's app pool goes to sleep and won't come alive again until the site gets another request, is that right?

Comment: @Matt Right. More acurately until the scm site gets another request.